# Format the date in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a date in an HTML template binding:

```
{{data.timestamp | date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" : UTC}}
```

and I want to use it in Javascript

```
$filter('date')(data.timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z', UTC);
```

But it didn't work in javascript. Any ideas what need to change in Javascript to make it works?

Comment: Why do you want to use the formatted date in your javascript ? It's typically best to leave your javascript dealing with integers, and format only on the frontend. The native js method of dealing with dates is the 'epoch millisecond' format, or number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01

Comment: Define "didn't work". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Do you have a variable UTC defined?

Answer (score 0):

You try redefine standard filter?
For [create new filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) use new `filter` module:

```
.filter('newDate', [function() {
    return function(date) {
        //date format;
        return date.getDate() + '-' + (+date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear();
    };
}])
```

Template:

```
//time = new Date;
{{time | newDate}}
```

Result:

```
3-9-2015
```